# adding a loss in tf keras purely in terms of the outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to enforce a structural prior on the two outputs of my network.
The network has two heads and each predicts a different quantity: f_1(x) and f_2(x) (and each branch has its own separate loss function).

I am basically trying to add a third loss that is a function of only the outputs: L(f_1(x),f_2(x)).

I know this can easily be done if I had a custom TF loop, but any idea how to accomplish this in Keras? (I am using tf.dataset to feed the input data).

Thank you

Comment: so i solved my own problem. This is not possible unless we subclass the model class in keras. Another way is to subclass a layer and route all the inputs and outputs through this layer and use add_loss function.

Comment: Here is one possible solution, using the "endpoint" pattern: https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/endpoint_layer_pattern/